# google.maps not found when trying to use google.maps.DirectionsService()

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps

I am still a bit new to the Google Maps API so any help is appreciated. Essentially what I am trying to do right now is take an origin and a destination from user input, and display step-by-step directions between those two routes. I have a button currently that when pressed should perform that option, however, I keep getting an error stating "Can't find variable: google" when trying to get directions. I am trying to do this through a JavaScript component, and I will include that component code below:

```
/* global google */
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, TextInput, SafeAreaView, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import DirectionsRenderer, { withScriptjs } from 'react-google-maps';

import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default
class Map extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super ()
        this.state = {
          origin: {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0
          },
          destination: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 },

          region: {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0,
            deltaLatitude: 0.09,
            deltaLongitude: 0.07
          },

          travelTime: 0,
          travelDistance: 0,

          directions: undefined,
          directionsRendered: false,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        Location.installWebGeolocationPolyfill()
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          this.setState({
            region: {
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              deltaLatitude: 0.09,
              deltaLongitude: 0.07
            }
          })
          console.log(region)
        });
        // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        //   console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
        //   console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
        // });
      }


      calcDelta(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
      {
        let maxLat, maxLong, minLat, minLong;
        if(lat1 > lat2)
        {
          maxLat = lat1;
          minLat = lat2;
        }
        else
        {
          maxLat = lat2;
          minLat = lat1;
        }

        if(lng1 > lng2)
        {
          maxLong = lng1;
          minLong = lng2;
        }
        else
        {
          maxLong = lng2;
          minLong = lng1;
        }

        const midLat = (minLat + maxLat) / 2;
        const midLng = (minLong + maxLong) / 2;

          const difLat = Math.abs(maxLat - minLat);
          const difLong = Math.abs(maxLong - minLong);
          this.setState({
            deltaLatitude: difLat,
            deltaLongitude: difLong,

            region: {
              latitude: midLat,
              longitude: midLng,
              deltaLatitude: difLat + 1,
              deltaLongitude: difLong + 1
            }
          });
      }

      calculateRoute(){
        this.state.directionsRendered = true;
        
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsService.route(
            {
                origin: this.state.origin,
                destination: this.state.destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            },
            (result, status) => {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(result)
                    this.setState({
                        directions: result
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                }
            }
        );
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View
          styles={{
            margin: 0,
          }}>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                placeholder='Origin Input'
                minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
                autoFocus={false}
                returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
                keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
                listViewDisplayed='true'    // true/false/undefined
                fetchDetails={true}
                renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
                onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                  //console.log(data, details);

                  this.setState({
                    origin: {latitude: details.geometry.location.lat, longitude: details.geometry.location.lng}
                  });

                  if(this.state.destination.latitude != 0)
                  {
                    this.calcDelta(this.state.origin.latitude,
                      this.state.origin.longitude,
                      this.state.destination.latitude,
                      this.state.destination.longitude);
                  }
                }}

                query={{
                  key: 'NoFreeAPIKeyForYou',
                  language: 'en',
                }}

                styles={{
                  textInputContainer: {
                    width: '100%'
                  },
                  description: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                  },
                  predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                  },
                  row: {
                    height: "25%",
                  },
                  container: {
                    flex: 0,
                    height: 100,
                  },
                }}
                debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
              />
              <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                placeholder='Destination Input'
                minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
                autoFocus={false}
                returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
                keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
                listViewDisplayed='true'    // true/false/undefined
                fetchDetails={true}
                renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
                onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                  //console.log(data, details);

                  this.setState({
                    destination: {latitude: details.geometry.location.lat, longitude: details.geometry.location.lng}
                  });

                  if(this.state.origin.latitude != 0)
                  {
                    this.calcDelta(this.state.origin.latitude,
                      this.state.origin.longitude,
                      this.state.destination.latitude,
                      this.state.destination.longitude);
                  }
                }}

                query={{
                  key: 'NoFreeAPIKeyForYou',
                  language: 'en', // language of the results
                }}

                styles={{
                  textInputContainer: {
                    width: '100%'
                  },
                  description: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                  },
                  predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                  },
                  row: {
                    height: "25%",
                  },
                  container: {
                    flex: 0,
                    height: 100,
                  },
                }}
                debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
              />
              <Button
                title="Press Me For Directions (Hopefully)"
                onPress={() => this.calculateRoute()}
              >
              </Button>
              {this.state.origin.latitude != 0 && this.state.destination.longitude != 0 &&
                  <Text>
                  Duration: {this.state.travelTime} minutes
                  {"\n"}
                  Distance: {this.state.travelDistance * 1/(1.60934)} mi
                </Text>
              }
           <MapView
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              apikey={"NoFreeAPIKeyForYou"}
              style={{
                width: 270,
                height: 270,
              }}
              region={{
                latitude: this.state.region.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.region.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: this.state.region.deltaLatitude,
                longitudeDelta: this.state.region.deltaLongitude
              }}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              followUserLocation={true}
            >
              <MapViewDirections
                origin={this.state.origin}
                destination={this.state.destination}
                apikey={"NoFreeAPIKeyForYou"}
                strokeWidth={5}
                strokeColor="blue"
                timePrecision="now"
                onReady={result => {
                  this.setState({
                    travelTime: result.duration,
                    travelDistance: result.distance
                  })
                }}
              >
              </MapViewDirections>
              <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.origin}/>
              <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.destination}/>
            </MapView>
            {this.state.directionsRendered &&
              <DirectionsRenderer
                directions={this.state.directions}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                apikey={"NoFreeAPIKeyForYou"}
            >
            </DirectionsRenderer>}
          </View>
        )
      }
}
```

I want to also note that I am attempting to implement this code in a react-native app.

If there is any additional information I need to provide please let me know - thank you for any help in advance!